# Creating a function that can take different types of variables

Tags: c#, methods

How can I make a function that can take different types of variables?
I want to make something like this:

```
MyFunction("text");
MyFunction(2);
```

I know it's possible because there are many coder who use these type of functions, but I don't know how to make it.

Comment: There is a [book](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx), which everyone should read.

Answer (score 7):

In `.NET` you can use the same method name with the same return type but with different number of parameters, and different types.

So, for example

```
  private string Return(string entity)
    {
        return entity;
    }

    private string Return(bool entity)
    {
        return entity.ToString();
    }
```

Both of them will return a `string` type, but will accept `bool` or `string`.

One other way would be to make a `generic method` which will take an `object`(not a basic type like `string` `int` `bool`) of that `type` as a parameter. 
Something like:

```
  private string ReturnType<T>(T entity) where T : class
   {
    return entity.ToString();
   }
```

Please be aware that the above will work as expected only if your `T class` has the `ToString()` method `overriden`.

As @StanR pointed, to use a generic method for basic types, use one which doesn't have the `where` clause, like:

```
  private string ReturnType<T>(T entity)
    {
        return entity.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: If the methods do similar things, keep in mind that you can also have them call each other to keep things cleaner and easier to maintain.  (If they do very separate things, however - name them differently.)

Comment: your 2nd example wont work since neither int nor string are a class

Comment: @StanR. I know, that's why i said that it will take an `object`, edited to make more sense.